# How to get css of all elements given a url using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to write a script that scraps through all the links when fed a sites url and checks if in every url if the font used on that page is `helvetica`, so i came up with the below script (part copied from online).

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var URL = require('url-parse');

var START_URL = "http://example.com/";
var SEARCH_FONT = "helvetica";
var MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT = 100000;

var pagesVisited = {};
var numPagesVisited = 0;
var pagesToVisit = [];
var url = new URL(START_URL);
var baseUrl = url.protocol + "//" + url.hostname;

pagesToVisit.push(START_URL);
crawl();

function crawl() {
  if(numPagesVisited >= MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT) {
    console.log("Reached max limit of number of pages to visit.");
    return;
  }
  var nextPage = pagesToVisit.pop();
  if (nextPage in pagesVisited) {
    // We've already visited this page, so repeat the crawl
    crawl();
  } else {
    // New page we haven't visited
    visitPage(nextPage, crawl);
  }
}

function visitPage(url, callback) {
  // Add page to our set
  pagesVisited[url] = true;
  numPagesVisited++;

  // Make the request
  console.log("Visiting page " + url);
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
     // Check status code (200 is HTTP OK)
     console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);
     if(response.statusCode !== 200) {
       callback();
       return;
     }
     // Parse the document body
     var $ = cheerio.load(body);
     var helveticaFound = searchForHelvetica($, SEARCH_FONT);
     if(helveticaFound) {
       console.log('Word ' + SEARCH_FONT + ' found at page ' + url);
     } else {
       collectInternalLinks($);
       // In this short program, our callback is just calling crawl()
       callback();
     }
  });
}

function searchForHelvetica($, word) {
    var bodyText = $('*').each( function(i , e) { console.log($(e).css('fontFamily')) } );
}

function collectInternalLinks($) {
    var relativeLinks = $("a[href^='/']");
    console.log("Found " + relativeLinks.length + " relative links on page");
    relativeLinks.each(function() {
        pagesToVisit.push(baseUrl + $(this).attr('href'));
    });
}
```

The problem i am facing is in the below function:

```
function searchForHelvetica($, word) {
        var bodyText = $('*').each( function(i , e) { console.log($(e).css('fontFamily')) } );
    }
```

The line `console.log($(e).css('fontFamily'))` will always return `undefined`. I believe cheerio has no way to access the css of an element. How can i work around this ? How do i get the `css` of each element on the page , run through each element and then check if the `helvetica` font is used anywhere on the page and return true or false based on this test ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make use of `getComputedStyle`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

something like:
`window.getComputedStyle(node, null).getPropertyValue('font-family');`

It will return a string (like `"Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif"`) in which you can search for the font

Given your exemple, I think you can do:

```
    function searchForHelvetica($, word) {
            var bodyText = $('*').each( function(i , e) { console.log(window.getComputedStyle($(e)[0], null).getPropertyValue('font-family')) } );
    }
```

**Note:**

As it is clearly stated in cheerio README:

> Cheerio parses markup and provides an API for traversing/manipulating the resulting data structure. It does not interpret the result as a web browser does. Specifically, it does not produce a visual rendering, apply CSS, load external resources, or execute JavaScript. If your use case requires any of this functionality, you should consider projects like PhantomJS or JSDom.

cheerio does not render/apply CSS.

So you should use jsdom (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) as it does support `getComputedStyle`.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik instead of cheerio you should probably use jsdom : https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom as it does support `getComputedStyle`

Comment: Thanks got ! will have to scratch my brains a bit more :D thanks a ton !